# How to store an ebook in sqllite and let it download in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, mobile

Currently I am working in my assignment which is to develop a Mobile App for a Book Library. I want to store an ebook in my table and let the user download it on demand. My book table has following feilds

```
BookId integer primary key autoincrement,
BookName text,
Picture blob,
BookData blob (ebook)
```

Can any one help me to overcome this problem. I would be much appreciate your help. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android Developers page describes [how to save data in a database](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).

I suggest that you do not store the book itself in the database, but on the file system. Name the file bookid.extension, or use any other unique identifier.

Comment: if I have so many books than bookid.extension technique is increase my app size or not.

Comment: Independent of the storing mechanism (like sqlite or file), the books will require space. If they are bundled into the apk, the app will be larger. If they're downloaded later, the space will only be occupied after downloading.

Answer (score 0):

The best  way is separate the book from the Database, the book has to be a simple file in any format you want, but if you put a book in a DB its hard to manage.

Book (PDF, EPUB,etc) in SD CARD
SQLite (books name, descriptions, authors, etc)